# Protractor data driven - Is displaying 'undefined' when I try to print JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, automation, protractor, data-driven-tests

I'm working with protractor and I'm trying to implement data driven.

I'm using this code that I found searching in google.

This is my **test.json**

```
{
"username":"testusername"
}
```

And i'm calling this **json** from my spec and trying to print in console:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var content = fs.readFileSync('test/e2e/tests/test.json');
console.log(content.username);
```

The test is not failing but in the console is print **undefined**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvtlZ.png)

I'm missing something? or i'm not implementing well the json?
Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do require(json_file_path). It will work. Try below code.

```
var content = require('test/e2e/tests/test.json');
console.log(content.username);
```

Comment: You right, is displaying now the json, but I add another value in the json file now I have this .
`{`
`"username":"testusername",`
`"password":"abc123"`
`}`
but the second value is not displaying, is saying again **undefined**

Comment: Is working now, I was redirect the require to another json but when I redirect to the correct json i'm getting all the information. Thanks @Suresh Salloju

Answer (score 0):

You are not parsing the JSON. `readFileSync` does read the file as a string. So `content` is a string containing the JSON, not an Object.

The solution is to simple use `JSON.parse`:

```
var content = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('test/e2e/tests/test.json'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

1. On Main spec:

   ```
   var testData = require('./Data.json');  
   describe('...', function() {

       testData.forEach( function (data) {

           var strUser = data.strUser;  
           var strPass = data.strPass;

           it('...', function() {
               <code here>
           });

       });

   });
   ```
2. On Data.json (which is located on same folder as Main spec):

   ```
   [{
       "strUser": "user1",
       "strPass": "pass1"
   },
   {
       "strUser": "user2",
       "strPass": "pass2"
   },
   {
       "strUser": "user3",
       "strPass": "pass3"
   }]
   ```

Hope it helps :)